# How to extract the filename from a request url using Regex in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I need to extract the filename + extension for any request having only a .aspx extension from within the request url. For ex. if the requested url is - http://www.abcd.com/index.aspx?a=1&B=2 then it should return index.aspx. If the requested url is http://abcd.com/products/pages/page1 then it should return empty.If the requested url is http://abcd.com/images/img1.gif then it should return empty.

Edit: If there is an aspx anywhere else in the url then it might pose the actual problem. but properly escaping the `.` and looking for the `.` within the url, and getting first match might solve the problem as hostname's usually dont have `.aspx` in them.

Comment: What should an url like `http://forums.asp.net/t/1775283.aspx/1` return?

Comment: @OscarMederos It should return 1775283.aspx of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
   Match fileNameMatch = Regex.Match("url", @"\w+\.aspx");
   string fileName = fileNameMatch.Value;
```

Comment: I know it returns www.aspx but may be it is suitable for @Siva Bathula because such urls are very specific

Answer (score 2):

I just want to throw my hat in the ring here.

Like most questions on StackOverflow.. Regex just isn't the answer. I mean.. it *is* an answer.. but it is similar to waking up a giant and asking it to squash an ant for you.

```
System.Uri uri = new System.Uri("http://www.abcd.com/page/index.aspx?a=1&B=2'");
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);
if (fileName.EndsWith(".aspx")) {
    // this is what you want
}
```

Comment: In case uri is 'http://www.abcd.com/page/index.aspx?a=1&B=2' you will get "pageindex.aspx"

Comment: @algreat Updated my answer to handle that and all cases.

Answer (score 0):

To extract only files ending with `.aspx` use this regex:

```
var r = new Regex(@"\w+\.aspx");
var match = r.Match(Request.RawUrl);

if (match.Success)
{
    //your logic here
    var filename = match.Value;
}
```

Comment: escape the `.` if you want to match a `.`